# Function is returning wrong type C

Tags: c, function

I have a problem with my function waveres. It is supposed to return a amplitude as a float, but does not. It return a random high number. I think it is the definition in my header file that is not "seen" by the main function. The other functions does work so I did not include them. When the waveres function runs, it prints correct values of amp.

Header file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h> /* til random funksjonen */
#include <stdlib.h>

void faseforskyvning(float epsi[]);
float waveres(float S[],float w[],float *x, float *t, float epsi[]);
void lespar(float S[], float w[]);
```

Main program

```
#include "sim.h"
main() 
{
  float epsi[9], t = 1.0, x = 1.0;
  float S[9], w[9];
  float amp; 
  faseforskyvning(epsi);
  lespar(S,w);
  amp=waveres(S,w,&x,&t,epsi);

  printf("%f\n", amp);

}
```

waveres:

```
#include "sim.h"

float waveres(float S[],float w[],float *x, float *t, float epsi[])
{
  float amp = 0, k;
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
      k = pow(w[i],2)/9.81;
      amp = amp + sqrt(2*S[i]*0.2)*cos(w[i]*(*t)+k*(*x)+epsi[i]); 
      printf("%f\n",amp);
    }
  return(amp);
}
```

Sample output where the two last number are supposed to be the same.

```
0.000000
0.261871
3.750682
3.784552
3.741382
3.532950
3.759173
3.734213
3.418669
3.237864
1078933760.000000
```

A source to the error might be me compiling wrong. Here is a output from compiler:

```
make
gcc    -c -o test.o test.c
gcc    -c -o faseforskyvning.o faseforskyvning.c
gcc    -c -o waveres.o waveres.c
gcc    -c -o lespar.o lespar.c
gcc test.o faseforskyvning.o waveres.o lespar.o -o test -lm -E
gcc: warning: test.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: faseforskyvning.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: waveres.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: lespar.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Comment: In C array indices are `0`-based. `float f[2]` defines the array `f` to have two elements: `f[0]` and `f[1]`

Comment: @alk Thanks for the heads up. Im new to programming in C and I thought that if I wanted a 10 element vector I should write float f[9] as that was the highest indices. I have fixed that in my code, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: @SM411 initialize your arrays. pow(w[i],2) => w[i] has garbage since you did not provide any initial value to it. Same with `S[i]` and `epsi[i]`

Comment: @Dabo I should have told that the values of w and S is defined in the function lespar which works good.

Comment: Do not change the question after answers have been given to it. This may make the answers ununderstandable. Apply changes by adding updates to the question.

Comment: @alk Sorry, I have reverted the comments. Is there any difference from writing a line in header file or before I start main? I moved the line  float waveres(float S[],float w[],float *x, float *t, float epsi[]); from header to main script and now it works. I still want to have it in my headerfile because I will be using the function in other functions.

Comment: "*Is there any difference ...*" It should be the same. Use the gcc option `-E` to see what will be passed to the compiler *after* the pre-processor has done it's work like `#include`ing.

Comment: Also make sure to always recompile all modules `#include`ing a certain header if the header had been modifed. Also^2 at least during debugging always compile with all warnings on (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc).

Comment: @alk Thanks for the tips. I have added my compiler log with -E to my question. Im new to C, and I have only done higher-level programming in Matlab before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have undefined behavior, you iterate untill `10`

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
```

But your arrays has size `9` which means the biggest index is `8`

```
float epsi[9], t = 1.0, x = 1.0;
float S[9], w[9];
```

You need to change your loop to

```
 for(i=0;i<9;i++)
```

Also your arrays are not initialized, this is also provokes undefined behavior. For example

```
 float w[9]={0};
```

initializes all elements of array w with `0`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about wrong array sizes. I still dont think that is what caused the error. If you look at the sample output that I have added the value of amp is not equal when it is calcuated the last time in waveres and returned to main. The arrays S and w get their values from the function lespar which reads values from a file.

Comment: @SM411 You can't expect the last value to be anything or to equal anything because it's a nonsense garbage value (since it's not in the array, it's just the result of UB.)

Comment: @user3477950 I thought that if I had a return value from a function, that I could write output = functionname(Input1,Input2). Is that wrong?

Comment: @SM411 this is absolutely fine, but in the last iteration you add to this return value some garbage totally corrupting it. Also initialize  your arrays.

Comment: @Dabo I have updated my code. The problem still occurs. I dont think the source was the errors was garbage in last itteration. No calculation is done after second last print and last print. The error occurs when the value is returned from the function waveres.

Comment: @SM411 Ok, what about `epsi` ? It also should have some inital values. Also try to use `double` for arrays and for `amp`, maybe you just don't have enough place in `float` to hold your results.

Comment: @Dabo Epsi is a vector of 10 random numbers between 0 and 2 pi. It does also work. I figured out if I wrote the definition of waveres in the main script file outside main, and not in the header, it works. What can cause that?

Comment: @SM411 Black computer magic ? :) I don't know, do you have [guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header file ? Add following lines in `sim.h` before your `#include` statements : `#ifndef SIM_H
#define SIM_H `  and `#endif ` at the end of `sim.h`

Comment: @Dabo I tried adding guards but it made no change. I can send you all my files if you want to compile them yourself.

Comment: @SM411 davidstdio@gmail.com , be my guest

Comment: @Dabo In the process of sending you the files, I did some cleanup of my script folder. When I recompiled the program it worked. I think there have been some files that caused problem. I guess it was the sim.o file.

Comment: @SM411 Perfect, i guess you just did not clean you project after adding guards.